# Indexing Error Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full\Interceptor does not exist Magento Version 2.3.5

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

Indexing Error :

**Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00 

Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:44

Category Products indexer process unknown error:

Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full\Interceptor does not exist

Product Categories indexer process unknown error:

Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full\Interceptor does not exist

Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00**

Log File Error:

main.CRITICAL: Class \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full does not exist
Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only. [] []

This project currently runs on a mac PC. I gave Full Permission to the folders for access.
generated,pub/static and var

Answer (score 0):

As the error states in its description, this is related to incorrect permissions on the Magento's "generated" folder on your filesystem.

Change the permissions to allow Magento to write that folder, so that it can create the Interceptor classes dynamically as it is required by the DI (Dependency Injection) features.

Or, if you don't have control over your system in runtime (for example because of restrictions as applied in Adobe Cloud where the "generated" folder is read-only at runtime), make the "generated" folder part of your code base, use Magento's "production mode" to compile DI (`php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command) and make the generated classes like the Interceptor reported in the error message part of the code you upload and/or deploy to your running Magento instance.

Bottom line, Magento relies of DI-auto-generated classes like Proxies, Factories, Interceptors etc, which allow for the Magento's Dependency Injection principles to work, so it needs to ensure these classes are in place (either pre-generated during the DI compilation setup step, or dynamically generated at runtime like in developer mode).